# pull off one the neatest tricks

Tags: phrase-usage

In the book "How an Economy Grows and Why It Crashes" by Peter D. Schiff, in an introduction, page xii, paragraph 2, there is the sentence:

> Essentially Keynes managed to pull off one the neatest tricks imaginable.

Can I parse the sentence above this way?

> Essentially Keynes managed to take one trick from the neatest imaginable  tricks

I knew from Lambie's explanation.

> pull off means succeed in doing something.

Another problem here is that how to understand object of `pull off`?

> pull off one the neatest tricks imaginable.

How to parse  `one the neatest tricks imaginable?

`one` is single,`the neatest tricks imaginable` is plural,what is the logic between them?

Did the author omit `of` between `one` and `the neatest tricks imaginable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**to pull off an x or to pull something off is an idiomatic expression and phrasal verb that is invariable.** It simply means: to manage to do something.

- He pulled off a neat trick.
- He pulled off a funny thing.
- He pulled off an amazing bait-and-switch.
- He pulled off a scam.
- How could the committee possibly accept that paper she wrote?
- Answer: I don't know but she managed to pull it off.

[pull off](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/pull-off)

Comment: How can a dictionary definition merit a downvote? This is as clear as a bell. It's really mystifying.

Comment: How to parse  `one the neatest tricks imaginable`?

Comment: Did the author omit of between one and the neatest tricks imaginable?

Comment: It's a typo (typographical error) or omission.